# Vuetify Maximize Height of v-list

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I have this very simple chat app here: [image]

It contains of a Header and then `v-main`. Inside `v-main` I first have a `v-container` containing a `v-card`. This `v-card` element has the `Name` as an title, then a `v-list` containing the messages, and finally, divided by an `v-divider` a simple `v-form`. The end of `v-app` also contains a `v-footer`.

**Treeview:**

`v-app`

- `v-app-bar`
- `v-main`

  - `v-container`

    - `v-card`

      - `v-card-title`
      - `v-divider`
      - `v-list`
      - `v-divider`
      - `v-form`
- `v-footer`

**Current code inside `v-main`->`v-container`:**
The `v-container`simply has the `fluid` property on it.

```html
<template>
    <v-card>
        <!-- Card Title -->
        <v-card-title>
          {{ messageInfo.sender }}
        </v-card-title>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <!-- Messages -->
        <v-list
          class="overflow-y-auto"
          v-for="msg in $store.state.messages"
          :key="msg.id"
        >
            <v-list-item>
                <Message :message="msg" :isSender="isSender(msg)" />
            </v-list-item>
        </v-list>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <!-- Send Messages -->
        <v-form v-model="valid" ref="form">
          <v-container>
            <v-row justify="center">
              <v-col :cols="10">
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="messageInfo.message"
                  :rules="messageRules"
                  :counter="maximumLength"
                  required
                  rounded
                  flat
                  background-color="primary"
                  color="tertiary"
                  @keydown.enter="validateAndSend"
                ></v-text-field>
              </v-col>

              <v-col :cols="1">
                <v-btn
                  :disabled="!valid"
                  color="tertiary"
                  @click="validateAndSend"
                  icon
                  large
                  fab
                >
                  <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-container>
        </v-form>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

**Question:**
**Can I maximize the height of the `v-list`-element, so that my `v-form` will always end right above the start of the `v-footer`, regardless of the contents of `v-list`?** I don't have the height of `v-list` set yet (I think this is the problem, but unsure which height to choose).

I don't want there to be a huge gap between my "content" and the footer.

Also, when there are more messages than in the image, the v-list will simply list them (won't cut off), which then of course pushes down the `v-form` and the `v-footer`.

I am very unsure how to do this and couldn't really find anything on google or the vuetify website.

It is not important that the messages are wrapped in a `v-list`-component. I just need a way to scroll through messages, if necessary.

*Additional information:*
I am very new to vuetify and I am using nuxt.js (don't think that's important though).

Comment: I think you can try using `height: auto` on your container.

Comment: Sadly didn't work (I added  `height="auto"` to the v-container)

Comment: **Fyi:** I changed the color of the `v-container` to black temporary. The Container really just is around the `v-card`

Comment: Flexbox might do the trick here. using flex:1.. I am pretty sure veutiy has some flex utilties.. trying add it to v-card

Comment: That didn't work, but I think using the Grid System is key here. I've experimented a bit, but didn't find a solution so far.

Comment: EDIT: Nothing worked so far, I added some code, which might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Height of card:

This layout create scroll card for screen height. You need to set  property `fill-height` for `v-container`.
Then you need to style card by `position: absolute`

```html
<v-container fluid fill-height>
  <v-card class="card">
    ...
   </v-card>
</v-container>
```

Styles:

```css
.card {
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 14px;
}
```

#### Stretching list in card:

Now you need to stretch `v-list`. I moved `v-for` from `v-list` to `v-list-item`. Then I just added
`d-flex` and `flex-column` on `v-card`. Last step is stretch the list by `mt-auto`

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="card d-flex flex-column">
    <!-- Card Title -->
    <v-card-title>
      {{ messageInfo.sender }}
    </v-card-title>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <!-- Messages -->
    <v-list class="overflow-y-auto mt-auto">
      <v-list-item v-for="msg in messages" :key="msg.id">
        <Message :message="msg" :isSender="isSender(msg)" />
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>

    <v-divider></v-divider>

    <!-- Send Messages -->
    <v-form ref="form">
      <v-container>
        <v-row justify="center">
          <v-col :cols="10">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="messageInfo.message"
              required
              rounded
              flat
              background-color="primary"
              color="tertiary"
            />
          </v-col>
          <v-col :cols="1">
            <v-btn>
              <v-icon>mdi-message</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

#### Scrolling list from bottom to top (pure css):

You also need to reverse scroll for list. You can easily do it by pure css with `transform: rotateX(180deg)`

Template:

```html
<v-list class="overflow-y-auto mt-auto scroll-container">
  <v-list-item class="scroll-container-item" v-for="msg in messages" :key="msg.id">
    ...
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
```

Styles:

```css
.scroll-container {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9+ */
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* Opera */
}
.scroll-container-item {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* IE 9+ */
  -o-transform: rotateX(180deg); /* Opera */
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. FYI: I didn't include the `.scroll-container-item`-class, as it flipped the messages by 180deg. Without it it works perfectly!

Comment: Oh nevermind, it was because you named the `.scroll-container` class from Styles differently in the Template. Thank you so much for the great work!

Comment: Thanks! I fixed the class in my answer.